# increase space between brace and equation

Tags: equations, braces

Using the package `mathtools` the output of this code

```
\[
     \begin{dcases*}
        l_{\epsilon} = (l_ul_d)^{1/2}\\
        l_k = min(l_u,l_k)
        \end{dcases*}
\]
```

is the following

[image]

Is there a way to increase the space between the brace and the equations?

Comment: Off-topic: Do please write `\min` rather than just `min`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to increase spacing for all `dcases` environments, you can use the `\renewcases` command from `mathtools`. Here is an extremist example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\renewcases{dcases}{\,}{%
 $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace\qquad}{.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial L_1} =
            \begin{dcases}
                \frac{1}{\rho } - 1, \quad & x<L_1 \\
                0, \quad & \text{otherwise.}
            \end{dcases} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I realised while writing the question that these could be two options:

```
\[
     \begin{dcases*}
       \quad l_{\epsilon} = (l_ul_d)^{1/2}\\
        ~ l_k = min(l_u,l_k)
        \end{dcases*}
\]
```

[image]